# Batch Script Won't Display Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch Script which when I run wont display a string variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
color 0c
set /a Copyed = 1
set /a File = %random%
set /a Origin = %~z1
set /a End = 0
set /a OSize = %~z1
if %~z1 LEQ 999 (
    set /a Size = %~z1
    set Z="Bytes"
)
if %OSize% GEQ 1000 (
    set /a OSize /= 1000
    set /a OEnd += 1
)
if %OSize% GEQ 1000 (
    set /a OSize /= 1000
    set /a OEnd += 1
)
if %OSize% GEQ 1000 (
    set /a OSize /= 1000
    set /a OEnd += 1
)
if %OSize% GEQ 1000 (
    set /a OSize /= 1000
    set /a OEnd += 1
)
if OEnd == 1 (set OZ="KB")
if OEnd == 2 (set OZ="MB")
if OEnd == 3 (set OZ="GB")
if OEnd == 4 (set OZ="TB")
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::: > %File%
echo :::::::::::::::::::::::
echo Original File "%1" Has A Size Of %OSize% %OZ% >> %File%
echo Original File "%1" Has A Size Of %OSize% %OZ%
pause
```

When I run this script using another file I get :

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::
Original File ""P:\Virus Testing\Fill.txt"" Has A Size Of 536
Press any key to continue . . .
```

In the file it creates I get this :

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::: 
    Original File ""P:\Virus Testing\Fill.txt"" Has A Size Of 536
```

As you can see neither of them display the varible %OZ%. How do I fix this? Thanks In Advance

Comment: Should `set Z="Bytes" ` be `set OZ="Bytes" ` ?

Comment: You keep adding 1 to `OEnd`, but the variable you declared and initialized at the top is `End`.

Comment: Lose the spaces on `IFs`. It's unlikely that `OEnd<space>` will equal `<space>1`.

Comment: @Noodles: `if` doesn't care about those spaces. (but it *does*  differentiate between a string and a variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if %OEnd% == 1 (set OZ="KB")
if %OEnd% == 2 (set OZ="MB")
if %OEnd% == 3 (set OZ="GB")
if %OEnd% == 4 (set OZ="TB")
```

Answer (score 0):

A few bugs in your script:

You need to initialize `OEnd`, not `End`

```
set /a OEnd = 0
```

You need a descriptor for `OZ` for bytes, something like

```
if %OEnd% == 0 (set OZ=Bytes)
```

And, each of the other checks needs to check the value of `OEnd`, not name itself:

```
if %OEnd% == 1 (set OZ=KB)
if %OEnd% == 2 (set OZ=MB)
if %OEnd% == 3 (set OZ=GB)
if %OEnd% == 4 (set OZ=TB)
```

Comment: Thanks I made the changes